# how to execute Git Push in command line and to skip hooks

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

If you have push-hooks configured to be executed automatically before each push (pre-push) how can you disable it for 1 time? (e.g. to ignore fresh uncommitted changes)

Answer (score -1):

Run in the command line:

```
git push --no-verify
```

This will push and will not execute hooks. The configuration will stay the same, so 'git push' will run hooks all next time.
Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks